# Keep all "Track Changes" formatting in the final version of a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to mark a Word document as a final version ***without*** losing the color formatting, strikeouts, comments, etc?

We're using an automated tool (Adlib) to render the Word document as a pdf and it's marking the document as final before rendering - thereby losing all of the formatting. Even if we save the document as "Final Showing Markup" Adlib changes it to Final before rendering as PDF.

Comment: Can you not mark the document as "Final Showing Markup", rather than "Final"? What tool are you using to convert to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need, you wish to be able to have a final version (for printing and more), but would still like to be able to see all changes in this final version since and older one.

If so, the easy way is to save two versions, the original version and the final version.
As a responsible user, you probably do that for backup.

Whenever you wish to print the document, just print the final versions.

When you wish to see the changes, compare the two version by:

(using Word 2007/2010 ribbon)

```
Review > Compare > Compare...
```

Select the `Original Document` and the `Revised Document` (final version) and click OK.

There you are. Now see the changes in colors.

Moreover, if you save many version, you can compare changes between each two version.